# JPA inharit fields without inheriting id field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

**Hi All**

We generally put 4 field in every table named as CREATED_BY , LAST_UPDATED_BY , CREATION_DATE, LAST_UPDATED_DATE , So i thought why not put this in single class *BaseDo* and than inherit this into the class like *EmployeeDo*. The problem is if i annotate this BaseDo with @Entity i have to put one @Id field which i do not want . Is there a way to achieve this  ?

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class BaseDo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6685603264139140757L;
    @Column(name="CREATED_BY" , nullable =false )
    private String createdBy;
    @Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_BY", nullable =false )
    private String lastUpdatedBy;
    @Column(name="CREATION_DATE", nullable =false )
    private Date creationDate;
    @Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_DATE", nullable =false )
    private Date lastUpdationDate;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class EmployeeDo extends BaseDo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4465521188079217243L;
    @Id
    @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID" )
    private String employeeId ;
}
```

**Thanks A Lot**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use @MappedSuperclass

Please check it

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html